# thread_local C++11, Error C2492 in VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I have class like this:

in CustomAllocator.h file:

```
namespace MemoryMgmt
{
  class PoolMemory 
  {
   ....
  }
}
class CustomAllocator
  {
  public:
    void * operator new(size_t i_size);
    void operator delete(void*, void*);
    virtual ~CustomAllocator(){}; 


#pragma warning(suppress: 4251)
    static thread_local MemoryMgmt::PoolMemory memory_manager_current;
  };
inline void * CustomAllocator::operator new(size_t i_size)
  {
  return memory_manager_current.AllocateChars(i_size);
  }
inline void CustomAllocator::operator delete(void * , void*)
  {
  //Should not be used
  ASSERT(!"Placement delete should not be used for memory objects");
  }
```

in CustomAllocator.cpp file:

```
#include <CustomAllocator.h>

thread_local MemoryMgmt::PoolMemory CustomAllocator::memory_manager_current;
```

I used CustomAllocator class in many different libraries. and I will get the following error (many errors same as):

```
error C2492: 'public: static MemoryMgmt::PoolMemory CustomAllocator::memory_manager_current': data with thread storage duration may not have dll interface (compiling source file D:\*******.cpp)
```

I use visual studio 2015 and I guess it is fully supported in this version.

Comment: It seems that you simply can't use `thread_local` (what MS is calling "thread storage duration") when you're creating a DLL. From the [error C2492 reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40a45kxx.aspx): "The address of the thread variable is not known until run time, so it cannot be linked to a DLL import or export."

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for your comment, but according to the https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx it is fully supported in visual studion 2015. Do I miss anything?

Comment: Just because the `thread_local` keyword is implemented and working for ordinary programs, doesn't mean you can still use it in a DLL. As the error is telling you.

Comment: Ok, Is there anyway to make it possible to use it in a DLL?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I see no mention of dll in the above code.  Are you thinking the OP omitted it?

Comment: @Yakk The OP mentions "many different libraries", and the error would make no sense if it wasn't in a DLL.

Comment: @H'H Is `CustomAllocator` actually marked up as a DLL export in your actual code?  If not, strange.  If so, why would you think the DLL export status of a type was irrelevant when the error message mentions dll?

Comment: @Yakk I do not see CustomAllocator marked up as a DLL export. The code is compiled if I remove thread_local. However I need thread_local in order to make it compatible with usage of parallel programming.

Comment: @H'H Is `CustomAllocator` being used by some other type that is DLL exporting it?  Consider moving the `thread_local` out of the declaration of `CustomAllocator`, and store it (as a global variable within an anonymous namespace) in a `.cpp` file?

Comment: @Yakk it works when I declared it outside of class in the same header file as a global variable.

Comment: You can *use* it, you can't *export* it.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when you use `__declspec(dllexport)` and `__declspec(thread)` together. In your case `memory_manager_current` is `static` class member used as thread local storage. However, I strongly suspect the class might have declared with attribute `__declspec(dllexport)` (Although not seen in the code in your post).

You can safely move `memory_manager_current` out of class and make it as global variable in the implementation file of `class CustomAllocator`.

Hope this helps.