# DLL for derived class C++

Tags: c++, dll

I have a base class as follows:

```
class Base
  {
  public:
    BASE_API     void * operator new(size_t, void * i_p) {return i_p;};
    BASE_API     void increase() {current_id++;};
    BASE_API     virtual ~Base(){};

#pragma warning(suppress: 4251)
    static thread_local int current_id;
  }
 thread_local int current_id;
```

in a different Library I am using a derived class:

```
class BASE_API Derived : public Base
  {
  public:
    BASE_API     void decrease() {Base::current_id--;};
    BASE_API     ~Derived(){};
  }
```

The reason that I did not write **class BASE_API Base** is that member with thread storage duration may not have DLL interface. So, I put BASE_API before every member of the class except thread_local member variable.

Now I get the following error:

```
error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated (compiling source file D:\****.cpp)
D:\****\Derived.h(37): warning C4275: non dll-interface class 'Base' used as base for dll-interface class 'Derived' (compiling source file D:\_****.cpp)
```

**Is there any other way to get rid of errors** except that the following solution:

```
#pragma warning (push)
#pragma warning (disable:4275)
class BASE_API Derived : public Base
  {
  public:
    BASE_API     void decrease() {Base::current_id--;};
    BASE_API     ~Derived(){};
  }
#pragma warning (pop)
```

Comment: @SimonKraemer I edited the question

Comment: Have you already checked the [msdn page for the warning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tdb471s.aspx)?
I think that just ignoring it is not a good idea.

Comment: I totally agree with u. That is why I ask this question. Otherwise, the solution (disabling warning locally) I provided works fine.

Comment: Have you already checked what Microsoft suggests? Is there any reason not to apply these rules to your code?

Comment: BTW please also note the comments for your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40744152/thread-local-c11-error-c2492-in-vs2015

Comment: Hmya, you have incompatible requirements.  The class has to be exported because it uses virtual members so something has to give.  There is no obvious need for the thread_local member to be exposed.  If you need it in the derived class then just add a GetId() member function.